Delphi 6 compiled without debug DCUs cause laggish application?
I have a larger Delphi (6) application. Recently wanting to make a release, I thought it would make more sense to compile without debug options.
I set the options as this.

If I build the application as shown, the response to interaction is sluggish: select a text box, click a button - sometimes, it's instant, other times I have to click 3-4 times. Almost like a service running in the background taking the power.
WITH the debug DCUs, all works perfectly as expected.
If it is relevant, the application uses FastMM4:
program MyProgramName

{$I FastMM4Options.inc}

uses
  FastMM4 in 'FastMM4.pas',
  FastMM4Messages in 'FastMM4Messages.pas',
...

I simply don't understand this difference, but it's solidly repeatable. Do anyone know the reason, and is there a downside to compile final EXE with Debug, as shown ?
Any other option I should set / disable for final release ?
The destination is Windows, 32 bit exe.

Of course the target is Win32, Delphi 6 can't target anything else ;-)

"I have to click 3-4 times" is always a wrong user input. No matter how "slow" the system is - the click (or anything else) is still registered every time, not just once when its consequences finally roll in. If that is your understanding of programs then please first assure that your system is not the problem (f.e. weird AV, Windows Search indexing...). I think D6 was bugged more than D5 and D7.

@AmigoJack understand, but the difference is completely repeatable. Example: input box. With debugger on, a click is registered immediately (focus given). Without debug as shown, there is a visible delay of ~1 second, but not always. So hence the feeling of "lagging". If compiling with debug DCUs make no difference, I might just leave it like that.
